# How to get data from table in single row and show as pug in javascript

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, loops, pug

I want to show the only single specific row from the table whose Student ID is submitted by the User into the form. I tried various things but did't work please help me out in this. How to do that Below, I also mention what I want and what I am getting I mentioned the whole of my code please check my views/databyid.jade >> written the complete problem help me in that?

What I Want >
Submitted ID is 1

[image]

What I Get >
Submitted ID is 1
[image]

Here is my
App.js

```
//data array
const students = [
  { ID: '1', name: 'Amit', age: '14', rollno: '11', class: '10' },
  { ID: '2', name: 'Rahul', age: '12', rollno: '18', class: '8' },
  { ID: '3', name: 'Aniket', age: '15', rollno: '16', class: '10' },
  { ID: '4', name: 'Ravi', age: '17', rollno: '15', class: '11' },
];

//Get all students
app.get('/stdata', function(req, res) {
  res.render('dashboard', { students: students});
});

//user input logic
app.post('/fetchstudent', function(req, res) {
  var userinput = Number(req.body.id);
  console.log(userinput);
  var isMatch = false;
  students.forEach(function(user) {
    if (user.ID === req.body.id) {
      console.log("success");
      res.render('databyid', { students: students});
      isMatch = true;
    }
  });
  if (!isMatch) {
    // only logs once even though there are multiple users
    console.log("No Match!");
  } 
});

app.get('/',(req, res) => {
  res.json(JSON.stringify((students)));
});

app.listen(port, () => {
  console.log('Server is running on the port:');
});
```

Here is my >>> views/databyid.jade

```
doctype html
html(lang='en')
  head
    style.
      table {
      font-family: arial, sans-serif;
      border-collapse: collapse;
      width: 100%;
      }
      td, th {
      border: 1px solid #dddddd;
      text-align: left;
      padding: 8px;
      }
      tr:nth-child(even) {
      background-color: #dddddd;
      }
    title Dashboard
  body
    h1(style='text-align:center;') API - 1       
    table.table.table-striped
      tbody
        tr
          th Student ID
          th Name
          th Age
          th Roll No
          th Class
        
      each n in students
        tr
          td= n.ID
          td= n.name
          td= n.age
          td= n.rollno
          td= n.class
```

Here is my >> views/dashboard.jade

```
doctype html
html(lang='en')
  head
    style.
      table {
      font-family: arial, sans-serif;
      border-collapse: collapse;
      width: 100%;
      }
      td, th {
      border: 1px solid #dddddd;
      text-align: left;
      padding: 8px;
      }
      tr:nth-child(even) {
      background-color: #dddddd;
      }   
    title Dashboard 
  body
    h1(style='text-align:center;') API - 1
    table.table.table-striped
      tr
        th Students ID
        th Name

      each n in students
        tr
          td= n.ID
          td= n.name
    h1(style='text-align:center;') API - 2
    |    
    form(name='form1', method='POST', action='/fetchstudent')
      table
        tr
          td Enter Student ID
          |         
          td
            input#stID(type='number', name='id', required='')
        |         
        tr
          td(colspan='2')
            input(type='submit', value='Save')
```

Answer (score 1):

```
// Try this //
    
    app.post('/fetchstudent', function(req, res) {
    var userinput = Number(req.body.id);
    console.log(userinput);
    var isMatch = false;
    
    students.forEach(function(user) {
    if (user.ID === req.body.id) {
      var stud=[];
      stud.push(user);
    console.log("success");
    res.render('databyid', { students: stud});
    isMatch = true;
    }
    });
    if (!isMatch) {
    // only logs once even though there are multiple users
    console.log("No Match!");
    } 
    });
```

Comment: Please give best answer for my solution